# storing resource files in .cshtml instead of .resx

Tags: c#, resources, razor, resx

Has anyone stored resource files in .cshtml instead of .resx?
I want to see an example.

Is it a better option to do it than to use .resx file?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing. Are you sure?

Comment: It's part of [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx), but that really has nothing to do with resource files AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom resource providers, those can do anything you imagine. Ocasionally you may want to place your resources on databases as a practical way to keep them up to date.

Take a look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Custom_Resource_Provider.aspx

It´s a bit old, but it applies to MVC and newer .net version.